# Discrepancies in LBP Currency Formatting Behavior Between Firefox and Chrome Using Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript

I've observed a discrepancy in currency formatting behavior for the Lebanese Pound (LBP) when using the Intl.NumberFormat function between Firefox and Chrome.

## In Firefox, the provided code snippet:

```
const options = { style: "currency", currency: "LBP"
 };
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", options);
console.log(numberFormat.format(654321.987));
```

Produces the result: "**LBP 654,321.99**"

## However, in Chrome,

the result is: "**LBP 654,322**"

I'm curious to understand the reason behind this discrepancy and whether there are specific browser settings or implementation details causing this behavior.

PS: I know about minimumFractionDigits attribute but my question here is more regarding this discrepency.

I am excpeting the same results as Firefox but I don't understand why Chrome is rounding up

Comment: Chrome is right here.  The LBP is not to be subdivided.

Comment: I am not totally sure regarding who is right. 
I can see that LBP has 2 decimal according to ISO 4217 
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

Comment: Well, that might tell us there is no correct answer.  Because of inflation, there are 150 LBP to the US penny, so in actual usage decimals are never used.